# Using scale range in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, scale, display

I am using ArcMap 10.8.

I add the UAV data for raster data(.tif).

But in my display, the data only display a particular scale(1:600).

I checked my scale range. But also set "show layer at all scales".

What can I do in this situation?

Comment: Is it very big? Try [building pyramids](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/build-pyramids.htm)

Comment: The data size is 23.03 GB.

Comment: Thank you so much! I solved it with your opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Since your raster is very big, the drawing could be taking so long you never see the image.

Try [building/rebuilding pyramids](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/build-pyramids.htm) to speed it up:

> Building pyramids improves the display performance of raster datasets.